# avoiding for each row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know if there a way to not have the `FOR EACH ROW` syntax in a mysql query?

Maybe a workaround or something?

I need to use an `after insert` trigger but the application insert multiple times as part of an insert.

So the trigger sees the data in a compounding fashion as part of every insert.

Comment: the application is in PHP. It is using a Drupal form module. If there was a way to do this on insert from that module, then that would work. I just want it to have the same functionality "at time of submission", which is why I was using an "after insert" trigger.

Comment: The only "workaround" would be to upgrade to a DBMS that supports statement level triggers.

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR EACH ROW` syntax is required in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger definition. MySQL supports "row level" triggers only. MySQL doesn't support "statement level" triggers for DML operations. This is by design.

---

Is there a workaround?

No, there is no workaround. An `AFTER INSERT FOR EACH ROW` trigger is going to get fired for every row that gets inserted. It doesn't matter whether there's a dozen separate INSERT statements that each insert a single row, or whether there's a single INSERT statement that inserts a dozen rows. The trigger will be fired for each row.

Within the trigger you can compare this or check that, and then you can conditionally branch around portions of code within the trigger. But there's no way to bypass the firing on an AFTER INSERT trigger for every row that gets inserted.

Comment: do you know of a workaround? Maybe a way to only select the last row affected by the trigger?

Comment: No, there's no workaround, the trigger is going to be fired for every row. You can include conditional tests in the trigger, and branch around portions of code, but you can't bypass the firing of the trigger.

Comment: what if I use a cursor?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. In the context of a trigger, a CURSOR could be used if you wanted to retrieve the results from a SELECT query and process each row individually RBER. In the body of the AFTER INSERT trigger, the column values of the row that was just inserted are available by qualifying the column names with `NEW.` e.g. `NEW.id` is a reference to the value of the `id` column of the row that was just inserted. I think there's a 'bigger problem' you are trying to solve, but I don't have a clue what that really is, So I can't recommend that your trigger should use a cursor.

Comment: This was another question similar that I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290287/multi-row-instead-of-single-row-data-transformation-with-trigger-in-mysql/22312246?noredirect=1#comment33905893_22312246

Comment: The problem isn't really the trigger firing; the problem is the "impedance mismatch" between the EAV model of the original table (each attribute value stored as a separate row) and the relational model of the target table. The `MAX(),MAX(),MAX()` query view is one approach to resolving the issue, but it's incomplete, it's not returning the identifier of the entity (group_id). I've left an answer for your other question. Briefly, use the `group_id` col to uniquely identify the row in target_table, and perform an update (rather than an insert) when the row already exists in target_table.

Comment: ok, I saw it and will take a look at it, it may be a few days before I get to it and I will let you know, thanks for the help

Comment: I see now (from your older question) Gordon started you down the path of the MAX(),MAX(),MAX() query. He did note that it's just one approach; I see he omitted the group_id column, but that was to match the list of columns in your INSERT. The approach he demonstrated has some performance advantages for large sets, like if you were transforming the entire EAV model table into a relational model table, like in an overnight data warehouse load. But inside a trigger, we can do it more efficiently, and NOT run a query and just handle the single attribute value that was just inserted.